# Laravel - update multiple records with different values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table , similar to this:

```
|   key    | value |
|----------|-------|
| limit    |    15 |
| viplimit |    25 |
| ..       |       |
```

And i have an array :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [key] => limit
        [value] => 10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [key] => viplimit
        [value] => 99
    )

...
```

Now , saying we have 100 rows. What would be the best way to update the table corresponding to the array ?

There would be the option of a query for each 100 row, but that is just bad performance.

Comment: if my answer was helpful, please upvote and choose it as best answer to thank me for my time.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$statement = "UPDATE mytable
    SET key = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'key'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'another_key'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'some_key'
    END,
    value = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 15
        WHEN 2 THEN 25
        WHEN 3 THEN 45
    END
    WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
");

DB::statement($statement);
```

Just think how to create correct query. If it's admin panel or something that will be run not very often, I'd just use iteration to keep things simple.