# How to Update Rows (with different data) in one DB Query Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm making a gallery with sortable photos with Laravel and jQuery UI Sortable.

My function in the controller gets a nice array:

```
$items = [0 => 22, 1 => 25, 2 => 45];
```

But there will be approx 150 - 200 photos in one gallery. Is there any chance to set one DB Query instead 150 - 200? Because my controller makes this at the moment...

```
<?php

foreach($photos['item'] as $position => $id){
    Photo::where('id', $id)->update(['position' => $position]);
}
```

But it creates approx 150 - 200 DB queries, which is awful.

**Edit #1**

Basically I need something like this (two corresponding arrays with ids and positions):

```
$ids =       [22, 24, 25, 34];
$positions = [0, 1, 2, 3];

Photos::where('id', $ids)->update(['position'] => $positions);
```

But I can't find anything about this approach.

Comment: is "mass update" there - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#updates not that you want ?

Comment: Not so much. I need find many rows with different condition and put new data into them.

Comment: In you example, are you saying ID 22 will update with position 0, ID 24 will update with position 1, etc?

Comment: Yes, exactly ..

Comment: In that case, you'll end up having to make as many update queries as you need to make updates, unless you opt for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915664/laravel-update-multiple-records-with-different-values).

Answer (score -2):

Take a look here: [Eloquent model mass update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430716/eloquent-model-mass-update).

Basically, you are looking for a mass or bulk update.